.NET Aspire OpenTelemetry HTTP endpoint
Is there an example of using .NET Aspire's OTEL HTTP port (18890) for browser-side OpenTelemetry setup?  My docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  aspire:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspire-dashboard
    ports:
    - "8000:8000" # web: http://localhost:8000
    - "4317:18889" # gRPC collector
    - "4138:18890" # http collector
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://0.0.0.0:8000
      DOTNET_DASHBOARD_UNSECURED_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: true
      DASHBOARD__OTLP__CORS__ALLOWEDORIGINS: '*'

Then the Vue.js app POST to http://localhost:4318/v1/traces but gets a connection refused.
Full code sample: https://github.com/robrich/net-aspire/blob/main/04-standalone

By default the dashboard uses 18889, not 4318

OK, you'll kick yourself... check your port mappings :)

18889 is the gRPC port.  18890 is the HTTP port.  Browsers can't do gRPC so they must do HTTP.  But no matter what I do, I can't get the HTTP port to connect.

In your example you linked, you mapped 18890 to 4138, not 4318

Ugh. You're so right.
